# How to perform POST using .NET Core 6 Minimal API in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, minimal-apis

I am new to .NET and I have to perform this. Assuming we have the connection string and the Environment variable setup, could someone give me resources or code or guide on how to do it?

I just need to upload a pdf file in Azure Blob Storage using Minimal API

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written and the issues you are running into with that code.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Minimal API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#differences-between-minimal-apis-and-apis-with-controllers), we can see that the Minimal API does not support the binding the IFormFile.

*No support for binding from forms. This includes binding IFormFile. We plan to add support for IFormFile in the future.*

So, to upload file in the Minimal API, you can get the upload file from the HttpRequest Form. Refer to the following code:

```
app.MapPost("/upload", (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    if (!request.Form.Files.Any())
        return Results.BadRequest("At least one fie is need");
     
    //Do something with the file
    foreach(var item in request.Form.Files)
    {
        var file = item; 

        //insert the file into the Azure storage
    }
    
    return Results.Ok();
});
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Then, to upload the file to Azure Blob Storage, refer the following tutorial:

[Upload images/files to blob azure, via web api ASP.NET framework Web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/130134/upload-imagesfiles-to-blob-azure-via-web-api-aspne.html)

Code like this:

```
     CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
     Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     string strorageconn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MyBlobStorageConnectionString");
     if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(strorageconn, out storageAccount))
     {
         try
         {
             // Create the CloudBlobClient that represents the 
             // Blob storage endpoint for the storage account.
             CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
             // Create a container called 'quickstartblobs' and 
             // append a GUID value to it to make the name unique.
             CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
             await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
             // Set the permissions so the blobs are public.
             BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions
             {
                 PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
             };
             await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions);
             var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
             foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
             {
                 HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
                 var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                 string imageName = ("images" + serverTime.Year.ToString() + serverTime.Month.ToString() + serverTime.Day.ToString() +
                                             serverTime.Hour.ToString() + serverTime.Minute.ToString() + serverTime.Second.ToString() + serverTime.Millisecond.ToString()
                                             + postedFile.FileName );
                 if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                 {
                     int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 1; //Size = 1 MB  
                     IList<string> AllowedFileExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
                     var ext = postedFile.FileName.Substring(postedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                     var extension = ext.ToLower();
                     if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(extension))
                     {
                         var message = string.Format("Please Upload image of type .jpg,.gif,.png.");
                         dict.Add("error", message);
                         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                     }
                     else if (postedFile.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
                     {
                         var message = string.Format("Please Upload a file upto 1 mb.");
                         dict.Add("error", message);
                         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(imageName);
                         cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = postedFile.ContentType;
                         await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(postedFile.InputStream);
                     }
                 }
                 var message1 = string.Format("Image Updated Successfully.");
                 return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, message1);
             }
             var res3 = string.Format("Please Upload a image.");
             dict.Add("error", res3);
             return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             HttpResponseMessage response2 = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.InnerException.ToString());
             return response2;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         var res = string.Format("Did not connect successfull.");
         dict.Add("error", res);
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
     }
```